# Limit the min value of videoZoomFactor when pinching to zoom.

Tags: ios, camera, zooming, avfoundation, pinchzoom

When I pinch to zoom using the method below sometimes the videoZoomFactor will go below 1 and the app will crash. How can I modify my method so that when I try to zoom to the min value the zoom factor doesn't go below 1. I am looking for a natural zoom and not simply adding the pinch scale factor to 1.

```
-(void) handlePinchToZoomRecognizer:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)pinchRecognizer {

const CGFloat pinchVelocityDividerFactor = 5.0f;

  NSLog(@"%f", atan(pinchRecognizer.velocity / pinchVelocityDividerFactor));
if (pinchRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([inputDevice lockForConfiguration:&error]) {
        inputDevice.videoZoomFactor = inputDevice.videoZoomFactor + atan(pinchRecognizer.velocity / pinchVelocityDividerFactor);
        [inputDevice unlockForConfiguration];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }
}
}
```